# Accessible nested multiselect list

Tags: javascript, html, form, user-interface

I'm trying to figure out the most accessible and semantic way to allow users to select one or more options from a hierarchical list. Think a taxonomy of categories and subcategories.

I came across a [Bootstrap Multiselect plugin](https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-enableClickableOptGroups) that emulates a `<select>` with clickable `<optgroup>` elements, but the way it's implemented doesn't seem very accessible—so I'm trying to create my own approach.

**Things that are important:**

- The state of a parent option should correctly reflect the state of its children
- Toggling a parent should toggle all children
- It should be easily understandable and navigable by users with screen readers
- Users with screen readers should be able to easily understand when options are children of other options
- It should properly rely on native HTML semantics, and when necessary, ARIA attributes

**This is what I have currently:**

```js
const setInputState = (el, state) => {
  if (state === 'indeterminate') {
    el.indeterminate = true
  } else {
    el.indeterminate = false
    el.checked = state
  }
}

const updateOwned = (el) => {
  if (el.hasAttribute('aria-owns')) {
    let state = el.checked
    el.getAttribute('aria-owns').split(' ').forEach(id => {
      let owned = document.getElementById(id)
      setInputState(owned, state)
      updateOwned(owned)
    })
  }
}

const updateOwner = (el) => {
  if (el.hasAttribute('data-ownedby')) {
    let owner = document.getElementById(el.getAttribute('data-ownedby'))
    let states = []
    let collectiveState
    owner.getAttribute('aria-owns').split(' ').every(id => {
      let owned = document.getElementById(id)
      let state = owned.indeterminate === true ? 'indeterminate' : owned.checked
      if (states.length > 0 && states.indexOf(state) === -1) {
        collectiveState = 'indeterminate'
        return false
      } else {
        states.push(state)
        return true
      }
    })
    collectiveState = collectiveState || states[0]
    setInputState(owner, collectiveState)
    updateOwner(owner)
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('.nested-multiselect').forEach(multiselect => {
  multiselect.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][aria-owns], input[type="checkbox"][data-ownedby]').forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('change', event => {
      updateOwned(event.currentTarget)
      updateOwner(event.currentTarget)
    })
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul ul {
  padding: 0 0 0 1rem;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend id="legend">Categories</legend>
    <ul class="nested-multiselect">
      <li>
        <label id="a-label">
          <input id="a" type="checkbox" name="option" value="a"/>
          <span>a</span>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label id="b-label">
          <input id="b" type="checkbox" name="option" value="b" aria-owns="b1 b2 b3"/>
          <span>b</span>
        </label>
        <ul role="group" aria-labelledby="b-label">
          <li>
            <label id="b1-label">
              <input id="b1" type="checkbox" name="option" value="b1" data-ownedby="b"/>
              <span>b1</span>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label id="b2-label">
              <input id="b2" type="checkbox" name="option" value="b2" data-ownedby="b" aria-owns="b2a b2b"/>
              <span>b2</span>
            </label>
            <ul role="group" aria-labelledby="b2-label">
              <li>
                <label id="b2a-label">
                  <input id="b2a" type="checkbox" name="option" value="b2a" data-ownedby="b2"/>
                  <span>b2a</span>
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label id="b2b-label">
                  <input id="b2b" type="checkbox" name="option" value="b2b" data-ownedby="b2"/>
                  <span>b2b</span>
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label id="b3-label">
              <input id="b3" type="checkbox" name="option" value="b3" data-ownedby="b"/>
              <span>b3</span>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label id="c-label">
          <input id="c" type="checkbox" name="option" value="c"/>
          <span>c</span>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Questions that I have:**

- Are nested unordered lists the best way to semantically communicate hierarchy?
- Is using `aria-labelledby` on subgroup `<ul>` elements referencing the parent option  helpful for understanding the relationship between parent and child options?
- Is using `aria-owns` on the parent option referencing the child options helpful for understanding the relationship between parent and child options?
- Are any of the above methods ineffective or harmfully redundant?
- What else would you change?
- Is there an altogether better approach?

Comment: This seems reasonable and clear... but I'm not an accessibility expert.